# File from a Delayed Job to Uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm trying to get this PDF I'm creating from a Delayed Job uploaded to s3 via an Uploader (using CarrierWave). Right now I have the PDF being saved into a tmp folder, just as a test (and it works). I've mounted my Order model, created a receipt attribute on my orders table where I want to store the path name to s3. Anyway, question is, how do I get this PDF file over to the Uploader? Any help appreciated!

I call this in my order_controller

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue PdfReceiptJob.new(@order.id)
```

Code for delayed job. Note it is now saving it to tmp folder.

```
class PdfReceiptJob < Struct.new(:order_id)

        def perform

            order = Order.find(order_id)

            # create an instance of ActionView, so we can use the render method outside of a controller
            view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {})
            html_template = view.render(file: "order/receipt_attachment.html.erb", locals:{order:order})

            # use wicked_pdf gem to create PDF from the HTML receipt template
            pdf_receipt = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html_template, :page_size => 'Letter')

            # save PDF to disk. Later, to be stored in fog, sent to S3, than saved back to our DB
            pdf_path = Rails.root.join("tmp", "marmoset-receipt#{order.id}.pdf") #ex: will be at tmp/marmoset-receipt215.pdf

            File.open(pdf_path, 'wb') do |file|
            file << pdf_receipt
            end

        end
    end
```

Code for uploader, so far:

```
class ReceiptUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/marmoset-receipt#{model.id}"
  end

  #set headers for pdf file 
  def fog_attributes
    {'Content-Disposition' => "attachment;"}
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  def extension_white_list
    %w(pdf)
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a model like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :receipt, ReceiptUploader
end
```

So at the end of your `PdfReceiptJob`'s `perform` function you should be able to add something like this:

```
order.receipt = File.open(pdf_path)
order.save!
```